# DLL should finish its operation although the referencing app gets closed

Tags: c#

I have a C# winforms project which has a reference to a library also coming from myself. The winforms app triggers some work to do for the library. Is it possible that the library can finish its work even if the winforms app gets closed?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible approaches:

- create a separate subprocess. Ending the parent process will not end the child, thus, the newly created task will continue when the parent app is closed
- make the parent app in such way that closing the main form doesn't end the application, thus, giving the application time to end all worker threads spawned during its lifetime

I am not sure which of the two I would recommend, both seem risky as chances are the long-running background operation will not finish in reasonable time. And then what?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that the library can finish its work even if the
>   winforms app gets closed?

No, not if that library is simply hosted in the main process.

You would need to do something along the lines of create a windows (or web) service and host the library in the service along with a message passing mechanism. Then call into it by having your windows application call a command on the service.